# JSF page loses values after forward to itself

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

Whenever I let a JSF page perform a forward to itself, it loses all it's entered form values. Is it possible for it to somehow retain this values?

Comment: what is the scope of bean that holds the data ?

Comment: The scope of the bean is `session`.

Comment: This is not normal behaviour. We're going need to see a SSCCE.

Comment: Could it be that, as long as there is no submit, no values won't be set in the bean?

Comment: Yes, but that's normal behaviour and not related to JSF. Perhaps you're just not submitting the inputs at all? Why would you expect them to retain?

Comment: Yes, I'm not submitting them. And now I no longer know why I'd expected them to be retained in the first place. Please make your comment to an answer so I can tick it as the right one.

Comment: I reposted it as an answer. In the future, please use `@nickname` to notify others of comment-replies on posts which are not their own (and whenever more than one person has commented on your post). I didn't see your comment reply until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will happen when you're not submitting the form's input values to the server at all. For example, when you're using an output link instead of a command link, or when you're using `immediate="true"` on the command link/button, or when the command link/button is been placed in a different form than the inputs, etcetera.

It's normal behaviour that those values will not be retained in the next view then. The scope of the bean really doesn't matter then. If you want to retain them in the next view, you've got to submit the form's input values along as well. Even when the bean is request scoped and you're doing a simple forward (not a redirect), then the input values will be retained.

Answer (score -1):

You should look at the scope of the values that you want to retain? view scoped values will only be available for the lifetime of the page, request scope, will be disregarded on a new page forward, so you have to look a bit more into your application flow.

Comment: Not true. The request scope will **not** be disregarded on a page *forward*. It will only be disregarded on a page *redirect*. Plus, OP mentioned that the bean is in the session scope.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the correction, didnt see the comments attached to the answer.

Comment: The comments are on the question.

Comment: Would it be a converter problem?? on a field??

Comment: Yep, didnt see the comments on the question